Setting Bootstrapping priority
I'm currently trying to bootstrap a SOFRTERM curve using CME 1M SOFR futures, 3M SOFR futures and SOFR swap rates. For no particular reason I want to use the 3M futures as a priority over the 1M futures. I'm using the SofrFutureRateHelper and OISRateHelper helper functions to add the instruments. My question is, can I enforce a priority using quantlib functionality e.g 3M, then 1M, then swaps on to the bootstrapping process, or is this something that must be managed externally to the ql objects (i.e by the programmer) and hence only instruments that are required for bootstrapping can be added. I hope that made sense !!

I was able to iterate through the existing helpers list looking for a duplicate Pillar date to the helper I was intending to add. If the PillarDate already existed in the helpers list then it was ignored else added. This seems to have worked.

Correct.  You need to manage the choice externally.
